# Read single key from console input

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I want to resume script execution immediately after any key is pressed kind of like C's `getch()` but I can't find a way. I also need to know the input so I can either call the function or not.

I considered calling `cmd.exe /c pause` but that doesn't return the input and `WScript.StdIn.Read(1)` doesn't resume execution after pressing a key. Instead, you can type as much as you want and, when enter is pressed, it only reads the first character. Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is possible in plain VBScript. Would switching to [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730938.aspx) be an option?

Comment: The Choice command can do what you want, sort of. See `choice /?`. Don't use cmd but use choice direct and test it's exit code in not 0 and not 255.

Comment: @Trigger, `choice` is close but doesn't quite work for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think you may be right. Unfortunately, powershell is not an option. If you answer that this isn't possible, I'll mark it as the answer :)